# Calling a Objective C function from C++ Code

Tags: c++, objective-c, call

I googled around and I find a million results to this subject. But none of the pages helps me. I think that I have a very common problem. I'm playing around with audio programming especially working with audio queues. The purpose of my program does not matter for explaining the problem. But in a nutshell: I get an error when I try to call an objective-c function from c++ code. So here is my code that contains the error:
AudioRecorder.h:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>


@interface AudioRecorder : NSObject {

}

-(void)setup;
-(void)startRecording;
-(void)endRecording;
-(void)playAlarmSound;

@end
```

And this is the implementation: AudioRecorder.mm:

```
#import "AudioRecorder.h"
#include <AudioToolbox/AudioToolbox.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

@implementation AudioRecorder

static const int kNumberBuffers = 3;
...
static void HandleInputBuffer (void                                 *aqData,
                           AudioQueueRef                        inAQ,
                           AudioQueueBufferRef                  inBuffer,
                           const AudioTimeStamp                 *inStartTime,
                           UInt32                               inNumPackets,
                           const AudioStreamPacketDescription   *inPacketDesc ) {

    AQRecorderState *pAqData = (AQRecorderState *) aqData;              

    if (inNumPackets == 0 &&                                            
        pAqData->mDataFormat.mBytesPerPacket != 0)
        inNumPackets =
        inBuffer->mAudioDataByteSize / pAqData->mDataFormat.mBytesPerPacket;

    UInt32 size;
    AudioQueueGetPropertySize ( inAQ, kAudioQueueProperty_CurrentLevelMeter, &size );
    char* levelMeterData = new char[size];
    AudioQueueGetProperty ( inAQ, kAudioQueueProperty_CurrentLevelMeter, levelMeterData, &size );
    AudioQueueLevelMeterState* meterState =  reinterpret_cast<AudioQueueLevelMeterState*>(levelMeterData);
    cout << "mAveragePower = " << meterState->mAveragePower << endl;
    cout << "mPeakPower = " << meterState->mPeakPower << endl;
    delete levelMeterData;
    [self playAlarmSound]; //<--- here I get the error: Use of undeclared identifier 'self'   

    if (pAqData->mIsRunning == 0)                                   
        return;

    AudioQueueEnqueueBuffer ( pAqData->mQueue, inBuffer, 0, NULL );
}
...
-(void)playAlarmSound {
    NSLog(@"Alarmsound....");
}
```

When I omit "[self playAlarmSound];" then everything works fine. So how do I call this Objective-C function from my C++ code?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`self` only exists in Objective-C methods and that is a C style function. You need to pass `self` from an Objective-C method to the inUserData when you set up the callback, then cast it back to the correct type.

```
//This is an example for using AudioQueueNewInput
//Call this in an Objective-C method passing self to inUserData
AudioQueueNewInput (
   const AudioStreamBasicDescription  *inFormat,
   AudioQueueInputCallback            inCallbackProc,

   // this is where you will pass (void*)self
   void                               *inUserData, 
   CFRunLoopRef                       inCallbackRunLoop,
   CFStringRef                        inCallbackRunLoopMode,
   UInt32                             inFlags,
   AudioQueueRef                      *outAQ
);
```

And your original implementation

```
static void HandleInputBuffer (void                                 *aqData,
                           AudioQueueRef                        inAQ,
                           AudioQueueBufferRef                  inBuffer,
                           const AudioTimeStamp                 *inStartTime,
                           UInt32                               inNumPackets,
                           const AudioStreamPacketDescription   *inPacketDesc ) 
{
    AudioRecorder *ar_instance = (AudioRecorder*)aqData;
    ...
    [ar_instance playAlarmSound];
    ...
}
```

Comment: True, but I'd argue that the underlying reason 'self' is missing is because this is not a method of the class, not because it's a C-style function. Any Objective-C object is usable within this function - it's just that 'self' is only available in methods of a class.

Comment: I believe that is what I stated "self only exists in Objective-C methods and that is a C style function" had a typo originally where it said an but that should convey the same message.

Answer (score 4):

This is indeed a common problem. `self` doesn't work here because this is not a method of the `AudioRecorder` class, not because it's Objective-C code. You're in an Objective-C++ file, so all valid Objective-C code will work. `[anAudioRecorder playAlarmSound]` will work fine, provided you have a good reference to `anAudioRecorder`.

So how do we get a reference if we don't have access to `self`? The usual way is to use the `void* aqData` argument of this function as a pointer to your `AudioRecorder` object. When you registered this callback, you told it what the `void*` argument would be, in this case a pointer to your `AQRecorderState` object or struct, which you don't seem to use anyway. Instead you can use a pointer to `self` when you register so that you can use that object here.

Another option would be to use a shared `AudioRecorder` object, in which case you would call something like `[AudioRecorder sharedInstance]` (a class, not an instance, method) to get the `AudioRecorder` object you want. Because the other answer here elaborates on the first method, here's how to use the shared instance option: Add a static instance of `AudioRecorder` and a class method `sharedInstance` to your `AudioRecorder` object, like this:

```
static AudioRecorder* sharedMyInstance = nil;

+ (id) sharedInstance {
    @synchronized(self) {
        if( sharedMyInstance == nil )
            sharedMyInstance = [[super allocWithZone:NULL] init];
    }
    return sharedMyInstance;
} // end sharedInstance()
```

Then, when you want to use the `AudioRecorder` from your callback, you can get the shared instance using `[AudioRecorder sharedInstance]`. This is a very useful paradigm if there's only going to be one `AudioRecorder` - it eliminates a lot of reference passing.