# How to send a message to self in a C function in obj-C?

Tags: objective-c, ios, audioqueueservices

I have a C function(a callback function in Audio Queue Services) and I want to send message to self. How to do that?
If I type in [self message], there is an error:

```
Use of undeclared identifier 'self'
```

Comment: provide more detail, by self you mean your class right? cant you just [self message]? since even if its a c function you can add objective c code. or by self do you mean your function as in recursion?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Calling a Objective C function from C++ Code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6958685/calling-a-objective-c-function-from-c-code)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**You don't perform objc messages in realtime callbacks, such as audio.** The reason for this is that objc messaging is not constant time, and may lock, resulting in missed deadlines, resulting in audio dropouts. Static or dynamic (`virtual`) C++ calls and C function calls are of course constant time, and suitable for realtime contexts.

*If it were not an realtime/audio callback*, then one option would be to pass `self` as the user info or context parameter:

```
void SomeCallback(t_stuff* const stuff, void* userInfo) {
  MONClass * Self = (MONClass*)userInfo;
  [Self doSomething];
}
```

Comment: Actually I am writing 'HandleInputBuffer' function where there seems to be no way to add a parameter like this. Is there another way?

Comment: @user1214321 Follow the link to the duplicated question for an example.

Comment: @user1214321 `HandleInputBuffer` is, apparently, the name of some function from some apple sample code or demo/docs -- the `HandleInputBuffer` function is used as an `AudioQueueInputCallback`. As an `AudioQueueInputCallback`, the first parameter `void* inUserData` would be the parameter I am referring to.

Comment: Thanks for explaining this. Do you mean that there is no way to analyze the recorded audio data in an obj-C way other than save them to a file first?

Comment: @Caleb good find! unfortunately, neither answer at the other question notes the consequence of locking in audio callbacks :(

Comment: @user1214321 you *could* use an objc instance for the `userInfo` parameter if you handle it strictly as you would a c struct -- direct ivar accesses, c functions, no objc messaging, no locking, no allocations, etc. in the callback. i've seen it before. so, you can analyze it using c and c++, or you can pass the objc object and handle it using pure c. also note that ARC would be forbidden in this context.

Comment: @user1214321 since audio queues often use 3 buffers, your callback may not actually be performed on the realtime audio thread. but you need to confirm this elsewhere.

Comment: @Justin,so is it better to first write them to a audio file, and then read from the file and analyze it?

Comment: @user1214321 maybe. maybe not. unanswerable. not enough context.

Comment: Some suspect assertions in this answer. Objective C messaging itself is no different from C or C++ function calls underneath, and you're also confusing the issue of constant time. There is nothing in the objective C dispatch procedure that would necessarily lock. Now, calling framework methods from a realtime audio callback might cause problems, sure… not least of which because audio callbacks are unlikely to be on the main thread.

Answer (score 3):

`self` is only meaningful in the context of a class definition -- it's a pointer to an instance of that class. Functions aren't part of any class, so there is no `self` pointer. If you want your callback to be able to send a message to a given object, you'll need to stash a pointer to that object where your callback can find it. That might be a global variable (ick), a `userInfo` parameter that's meant for just this sort of thing (much better), or somewhere else.

Comment: +1 for giving the reason why you *can't* use `self` in a C function (the accepted answer only says why you shouldn't use Objective-C message passing in audio callbacks, not why you can't reference `self`)